# Android UI Automator Viewer

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to use UIAutomator Viewer from Android SDK 6.0. When I connect a device with version 5.1.1 or above, I am unable to capture the UI Layout. It says the following:

> Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: 
>   Remote object doesn't exist!

Did anyone face the same issue on the latest versions only? If so, please let me know the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced that error but I disconnect the device and connect it again and it works fine.
Oh and if you're interacting with it (UiAutomator, Espresso, w/e) it won't let you capture the UI with the UiAutomatorViewer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

@sah check whether your device is connected with some other server like if you are using appium and its  running then you will not get the screens and you will get that error .So make sure that the app device is not connected with any server and running.
Otherwise disconnect adb devices and connect again with your device.It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Kill existing running instances of uiautomator and run again.